# Problem with 32-bit COM component from 64-bit application. (TYPE_E_CANTLOADLIBRARY)

Tags: com, com-interop

I have a created a dummy application for testing purposes which is a 64-bit console application, which creates an instance of a 32-bit COM application. It is a third party application called Laserforms.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    LFM32.Application application;

    try
    {
        application = new LFM32.Application();
        Console.WriteLine("Success!");
        application.Quit();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
    }
    finally
    {
        Console.Read();
    }
}
```

Now, this works perfectly on my machine, but when I deploy it to another machine, which has Laserform installed as well I am getting the below error message.

> {System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast COM object of type 'System.__ComObject' to interface type 'LFM32.Application'.
> This operation failed because the QueryInterface call on the COM component for the interface with IID '{6688DD46-3DA3-4FEC-8A1F-54E1453DCC77}'
> failed due to the following error: Error loading type library/DLL. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80029C4A (TYPE_E_CANTLOADLIBRARY)).}

I have go one through the registry of both and can't see any differences, what else could I be doing wrong?

**UPDATE:**

So I ran TlbImp on the .tlb file to create a DLL I could reference in my .NET application. This created a couple of extra DLLs and some warnings around Iunknown and some invalid types. I then ran Regasm (from Framework and Framework64) on this and the other DLLs it created but I am still seeing the exact same error.

Comment: {6688DD46-3DA3-4FEC-8A1F-54E1453DCC77} is a custom guid specific to your context. It looks like your LFM32.Application program is not deployed properly. It may also be a 32bit vs 64bit issue.

Comment: @SimonMourier I have used the same deployment on of the Laserform application on both my local machine and the virtual machine. yes it works correctly using a 32-bit version of the test application, but I don't understand why the 64-bit one works on my local machine and not the virtual machine, any ideas what could be different?

Comment: A tlb must be registered somehow (it can be a standalone .tlb file, or a .dll that contains the .tlb as a resource). It's a deployment issue. You can use ProcMon from sysinternals (filter on registry access) to determine what keys are looked for using guids, etc.

Comment: I have an added an update to my question, if there's anything else you can suggest, appreciate your help so far.